# Order having multiple addresses of different kinds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have models for Order and Address and would like each instance of Order to have a shipping and billing address from the Address table. I am trying to figure out the best way to set this up but can't get it to work.

I tried:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end

has_one :billing_address, -> { where type: 'billing' }, class_name: "Address"
has_one :shipping_address, -> { where type: 'shipping' }, class_name: "Address"
```

which does not work but hopefully should give a sense of what I'm trying to do. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The approach is correct, but don't use `type` for your column name, it is reserved for STI. You can change the default STI column for your model, however I would prefer using column name like `address_type` or `context`. Also, for the future, please avoid using sentences like `which does not work` without giving explanation on how it does not work - there is a huge difference between exception and misbehaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple approaches for this as follows -

**Approach 1:** Using builtin STI (Single Table Inheritance) mechanism.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :billing_address
  has_one :shipping_address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

  # make sure that there is an `order_id` field 
  # and `type` field on `addresses` table for STI
end

class BillingAddress < Address    
end

class ShippingAddress < Address    
end
```

Example:

```
order = Order.new

billing_address = BillingAddress.new(content: '123 doggy lane')
order.billing_addresss = billing_address

shipping_address = ShippingAddress.new(content: '123 doggy lane')
order.shipping_address = shipping_address

order.save!
```

**Approach 2:** Using custom STI (Single Table Inheritance) mechanism.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :billing_address
  has_one :shipping_address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

  # make sure that there is an `order_id` field 
  # and `address_type` field on `addresses` table for custom STI
  # important note: make sure its `address_type`, not `type`
  # if it is `type`, rails builtin STI kicks in

  validates_inclusion_of :address_type, in: ['shipping', 'billing']
end
```

Example:

```
order = Order.new

billing_address = Address.new(address_type: 'billing', content: '123 doggy lane')
order.billing_addresss = billing_address

shipping_address = Address.new(address_type: 'shipping', content: '123 doggy lane')
order.shipping_address = shipping_address

order.save!
```

**Approach 3:** Storing the address information in the `order`, instead of the other way around.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :billing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'billing_address_id'
  belongs_to :shipping_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'shipping_address_id'

  # make sure that there are `billing_address_id` and `shipping_address_id` 
  # fields setup on the `orders` table
end   

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :billable_orders, class_name: 'Order', foreign_key: 'billing_address_id'
  has_many :shippable_orders, class_name: 'Order', foreign_key: 'shipping_address_id'
end
```

Example:

```
order = Order.new

billing_address = Address.new(content: '123 doggy lane')
order.billing_addresss = billing_address

shipping_address = Address.new(content: '123 doggy lane')
order.shipping_address = shipping_address

order.save!
```

Comment: Does it also handle multiple address per Model. For instance an User can have many Billing Addresses. Or does this code has to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do what your asking

**migrations**

```
rails g migration CreateOrders
rails g migration CreateAddresses shipping_id:integer billing_id:integer content:string
rake db:migrate
```

**classes**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipping_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'shipping_id'
  has_one :billing_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: 'billing_id'
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

**implementation**

```
rails c

order = Order.create
address = Address.create(content: '123 doggy lane')
order.shipping_address = address
order.billing_address = address
order.save!

order.shipping_address
#=> #<Address id: 1, shipping_id: 1, billing_id: 1, content: "123 doggy lane">
order.billing_address
#=> #<Address id: 1, shipping_id: 1, billing_id: 1, content: "123 doggy lane">
```