# Profile having Address of different kinds and 2 profiles may share the same address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a `Profile` table that would have one work address and one home address. Multiple profiles can share the same home address if the user for those profiles live together (or work address if they work together). What are some ways I can achieve this? I think `has_many :through` would work in this case, but I can't think of a way to implement this.

Ideally, I want to be able to to do something like `Profile.home_address` or `Profile.addresses.where(address_type: "home")`

I saw this thread when I was looking for some answers:
[Order having multiple addresses of different kinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636267/order-having-multiple-addresses-of-different-kinds)

Approach 1 and 2 seem to not work for my case because the foreign key is in the `Address` table, which would allow an address to be tied to only one `Profile`. Approach 3 would work but I was just wondering if there's another way to do it. Having a `home_address_id` and `work_address_id` seem to suggest I have a `HomeAddress` and `WorkAddress` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you probably want `Profile` and `Address` to have a m:m relationship. That might look something like:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :profile_addresses
  has_many    :addresses, through: :profile_addresses
  belongs_to  :user
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_addresses
  has_many :profiles, through: :profile_addresses
end

class ProfileAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :address
end
```

Now, you can do `@profile.addresses`. If you want to be able to do `@profile.home_address` (not `Profile.home_address` since you want to call the method on an instance, not a class), then you would do something like:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :profile_addresses
  has_many    :addresses, through: :profile_addresses
  belongs_to  :user

  def home_address
    addresses.where(address_type: 'home').first
  end

end
```

Note: If `@profile` happens to have more than one `address` with `address_type: 'home'`, then `.first` may or may not give unexpected results.

If you have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  delegate :home_address, to: :profile
end
```

Then you can do `@user.home_address`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming following scenarios:

- A profile can have multiple addresses, but only **one** of each type i.e. 'home', 'work', etc.
- An address can be associated to **multiple** profiles, in case people live in same house or work at same office.
- An address can be 'home' address for one profile (user) and same address can be 'work' address for another profile (user) (It is *possible*, isn't it?).

I ended up with an approach as simple as below:

```
class Profile
  has_many :profile_addresses

  def home_address
    profile_addresses.where(tag: 'home').first&.address
  end

  def work_address
    profile_addresses.where(tag: 'work').first&.address
  end
end

class ProfileAddress
  # field :tag

  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :address
end

class Address      
end
```

Let's create and access some records now:

```
profile_1 = Profile.find(1)

address_1 = Address.create(
  street: '22-Block',
  region: 'Connaught Place',
  city: 'New Delhi',
  state: 'Delhi',
  country: 'IN'
)

# Say, `profile_1` has above `address_1` as its home address
profile_1.profile_addresses.create(tag: 'home', address: address_1)

address_2 = Address.create(
  street: 'Street-43',
  region: 'Raja Garden',
  city: 'Mohali',
  state: 'Punjab',
  country: 'IN'
)

# `profile_1` has above `address_2` as its work address
profile_1.profile_addresses.create(tag: 'work', address: address_2)

# Another profile
profile_2 = Profile.find(2)

# Now, say, `profile_2` has `address_1` as its work address
profile_2.profile_addresses.create(tag: 'work', address: address_1)

# Fetching...
profile_1.home_address
 => address_1

profile_1.work_address
 => address_2

profile_2.home_address
 => nil

profile_2.work_address
 => address_1
```